# Multiple Highlights/Selects in C# with different colors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for a way to highlight a word and a sentence at the same time in C#. An example of what I am trying to accomplish is shown below.

[image: Created from MS Word]

I am working with windows forms, but I would be able to port over to WPF if nessassary.

I have been trying to accomplish this with a rich text box, but I cant seem to find a method to do what I want. Is there anything out there that could accomplish this?

Comment: I don't have example code handy; changing colors in RTF requires establishing the color codes beforehand, etc. Consider doing a two-pass search and replace. Replace instances of the sentence with versions that have the color codes pre- and appended. Then do a second pass for the word(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k.aspx) the start of the sentence, set the [SelectionBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor.aspx), then [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9be0980x.aspx) the word you're looking for from the offset of the previous `Find()` call and set the [SelectionBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor.aspx) again.

Comment: That works, I was doing it backwards. Setting the selection back color then selecting, then selecting again.